# Flutter version issues when update to Flutter 2.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter2.0

All my classes are getting errors after updating.
I tried flutter clean as well. When ever i run flutter pub get command i get the following error.

```
Because no versions of intl_utils match >1.8.0 <1.9.0 and intl_utils ^1.9.0 depends on intl_translation 0.17.10+1, intl_utils >1.8.0 <2.0.0 requires intl_translation 0.17.10+1.
And because intl_utils 1.8.0 depends on intl_translation 0.17.10 which depends on intl >=0.15.3 <0.17.0, intl_utils ^1.8.0 requires intl >=0.15.3 <0.17.0 or intl_translation 0.17.10.
And because intl_translation 0.17.10 depends on intl >=0.15.3 <0.17.0 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0, intl_utils ^1.8.0 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
So, because markets depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and intl_utils ^1.8.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because markets depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and intl_utils ^1.8.0, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: The error is clear. Not all plugins got updates to work with flutter 2. That's why people say , check compatibility before upgrading core/ plugins in existing project.

Comment: What should i do to resolve these errors? Downgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try to downgrade your flutter version. I had the same issue

```
flutter downgrade 1.22.6
```